# how to pass the variable from the nested function call

Tags: javascript, jquery, jsplumb

I am doing a nested function call but with the same time I need to pass the variable to the nested function can i do that. Here is what I am trying to do so

```
allSourceEndpoints.push(jsPlumb.addEndpoint(toId, sourceEndpoint(index), { anchor:sourceAnchors[i], uuid:sourceUUID }));


sourceEndpoint(index) = {
            endpoint:"Dot",

            paintStyle:{ fillStyle:"#225588",radius:3 },
            isSource:true,
            isTarget:true,
            maxConnections:-1,
        //  connector:[ "Flowchart", { stub:[40, 60], gap:10 } ],
        //  connector:[ "Flowchart"],

            hoverPaintStyle:connectorHoverStyle,
            connectorHoverStyle:connectorHoverStyle,
            dragOptions:{},
            overlays:[
                [ "Label", { 
                    location:[0.5, 1.5], 
                    label:""+startEnd[index].start,
                    cssClass:"endpointSourceLabel",
                } ]
            ]
        }
```

The above code does not work because of the

```
       index
```

passing that i am doing. I need that as i need to find out the start. If I remove that index reference and the line

```
         label:""+startEnd[index].start,
```

it works fine but I really need to include that. Is there a way to do this??

Thanks a lot for the help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change the sourceEndPoint construct to a function and return the JSON object as a return value.
i.e.:

```
sourceEndpoint = function(index) {

    return {
            endpoint:"Dot",

            paintStyle:{ fillStyle:"#225588",radius:3 },
            isSource:true,
            isTarget:true,
            maxConnections:-1,
        //  connector:[ "Flowchart", { stub:[40, 60], gap:10 } ],
        //  connector:[ "Flowchart"],

            hoverPaintStyle:connectorHoverStyle,
            connectorHoverStyle:connectorHoverStyle,
            dragOptions:{},
            overlays:[
                [ "Label", { 
                    location:[0.5, 1.5], 
                    label:""+startEnd[index].start,
                    cssClass:"endpointSourceLabel",
                } ]
            ]
        };
    }
```

Comment: +1 - I was thinking the same thing was wrong. There has to be a function in order to pass a variable in like that. A plain object `{}` will not accept arguments in the fashion defined in the question.

Comment: @Chandu: This does work. But this whole call is in the for loop. I don't know why it is not calling the function on the last last value. Any idea why is this happening? Thanks

Comment: @unix_user:Can you post the source code of the whole context. Maybe a JSFiddle would be better

Comment: @Chandu: Here is the fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/AeYs4/1/

The for loop at the beginning gets called first

Comment: @unix_user I am unable to figure out what could be wrong with the code that you have posted in the comment. Can you update the question with the code?

Comment: @Chandu: I have added the jsfiddle link. Here it is  http://jsfiddle.net/AeYs4/1/

The code starting point is the for loop at the beginning. I checked with alert, once the value reaches the last value of the for loop of  j, the alert(index) does not come. I don't know why is this happening

Comment: I guess startEnd index access is throwing error. Change the first for loop to `for(j=1;j<xmlLength;j++) { 
    alert("The j is ::"+j+" the xmlLength is :"+xmlLength);
     var wind = "window"+j; 
     _addEndpoints(wind, ["LeftMiddle"], ["RightMiddle"],j); 
     //_addEndpoints(wind, ["LeftMiddle", "BottomCenter"], ["TopCenter", "RightMiddle"]); 
}`

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/18761/discussion-between-chandu-and-unix-user)